# Carrierwave file upload w/ resque job to upload to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

What would be the best solution to upload files to file storage, upload to S3 (via Resque), and then modify the storage type for carrierwave on the record? Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the [carrierwave_backgrounder](https://github.com/lardawge/carrierwave_backgrounder) gem which has Resque support for uploading files to S3 in the background after the file has hit your server.

Alternatively you could try uploading directly to S3 from the user's browser using the new CORS support. Eg. [s3_direct_upload](https://github.com/waynehoover/s3_direct_upload)